# How can I find radius from center in MKMapView in iphone programming?

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit

I have to send radius to web-service and it will return the data of stores back to iPhone.  It is pretty good when I am sending radius as digit such as 45, 60, or whatsoever, but what if I am on map and want longitude and latitude from map and want to know radius of visible area?

I am visible `MKMapView`, and I want radius from center of visible area, what can I do to achieve it?